# Using Python to insert a row into Postgres database - not working due to something in the structure of the insert statement? maybe

Tags: python, postgresql, sql-insert

I am trying to insert a row into a table in **Postgres** using **Python**, but it is failing.  Table is to house the failed insert data from a different insert on a different table, plus the error code and table it was trying to insert into.

**An insert query to my error_table that works is:**

```
insert into error_table(id, table, baditem, error) 
values(nextval('error_table_id_seq'), 'testtable','{"testbaditem":"testbaditem"}'::json,'testerror');
```

**Table structure:**

| Column | Type | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint | not null | nextval('error_table_id_seq'::regclass) |
| table | character varying |  |  |
| baditem | jsonb |  |  |
| error | character varying |  |  |

**Example data already in table:**

| id | Type | Nullable | Default |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | table_namet | {"data1": "data1_value","data2": "dat2_value", | invalid input syntax for type |
|  |  | "data2": "dat2_value", | numeric: "null" |
|  |  | "data2": "dat2_value"} |  |

**Sample code I am trying to get working.** It is being called and populated from a different .py file.

---

```
import psycopg2
class Feeder:
    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection  
        
    def error_data(self, table, badItem, error):
        errorTable = 'table1'
        args = (table, badItem, error)  
        e=error
        bi=badItem
        t=table
        print('Error: %s,  badItem:  %s , Table:  %s' %(e,bi,t))
        insertStmnt = "INSERT INTO error_table (id,table, item, error)  VALUES(nextval('select error_table_id_seq')," +str(t)+", "+str(bi)::json+"," +str(e)+ ")"
      
        print(insertStmnt)
      
        try:
            cursor = self.connection.cursor()
            dd = cursor.execute(insertStmnt)
            
            if cursor.lastrowid:
                print('last insert id', cursor.lastrowid)
            else:
                print('last insert id not found')
    
            self.connection.commit() # <- We MUST commit to reflect the inserted data
        except Exception as er:
            print(er)
    
        finally:
            cursor.close()
```

---

**Error I get:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file1.py", line 5, in <module>
    from feeder import Feeder
  File "/home/ec2-user/environment/error_feeder.py", line 13
    insertStmnt = "INSERT INTO error_table (id,table, item, error)  VALUES(nextval('select >error_table_id_seq')," +str(t)+", "+str(bi)::json+"," +str(e)+ ")"
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This `print('Error: %s,  badItem:  %s , Table:  %s' %(e,bi,t)` is missing a closing ")".

Comment: Also, don't use string concatenation for SQL statements

Comment: Also do not use string formatting for supplying values to query.  See here [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) for proper methods.

Comment: You dont have to specify the `id` if it's already specified as a default via a sequence.  (if you do need it, there is a `returning` instruction in postgres).  Try leaving it out.  Plus, second that dont-build-queries-from-string.  Pretty horrible security risk.

Comment: Adrian, fixed, thanks. Left that out in the editing, but not the important code, just code that proved data was coming over at one point in time from the code on the other page.

Comment: Adrian, I don't know how I missed the Parameters page.  Thanks! That makes so much sense.  I'll give it a shot soon. Looks like I had complicated it needlessly, although I still don't know why what I had doesn't work. Will try this and keep you posted:     cur.execute("INSERT INTO error_table (id,table, item, error) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)”, (t, bi, e ))

Comment: JL Peyret- I had tried Postgres table row insertion without the id, but only worked putting the id in.  Don't know why.  That's why I stated that that insertion code works.  I tried it in psql both ways.

Comment: The Traceback was garbled in the original post. Further study revealed that the issue was with this, `"+str(bi)::json+"`. In particular the `::json`, that is not Python syntax. For working with JSON in `psycopg2` see here [JSON](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#adapt-json)